# Passing variables into template inclusion spacebars and regular spacebars in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I've got lots of these similar blocks inside my templates.

The only real difference between each block is the `sku` (ex. `hdrPhotos, panos, twilightPhotos, exteriors`).

I would much rather write a single template that takes a `sku` argument and loop through an array of skus to create each block, but how would I insert a value into something that's already using spacebars {{ }} ?

`{{> afFieldInput name="servicesSelected.hdrPhotos.selected" type="boolean-checkbox" noselect="true"}}`,

`{{formatToCurrency currentPrice.hdrPhotos}}` or

`{{{services "hdrPhotos" "html"}}}` ?

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{> afFieldInput name="servicesSelected.hdrPhotos.selected" type="boolean-checkbox" noselect="true"}}
      <div class="divider small-margins">
      </div>
      <div class="item-description">
        <p><b>{{formatToCurrency currentPrice.hdrPhotos}}</b> - {{services "hdrPhotos" "description"}}</p>
        <p>{{{services "hdrPhotos" "html"}}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{> afFieldInput name="servicesSelected.panos.selected" type="boolean-checkbox" noselect="true"}}
      <div class="divider small-margins">
      </div>   
      <div class="item-description">
        <p><b>{{formatToCurrency currentPrice.panos}}</b> - {{services "panos" "description"}}</p>
        <p>{{{services "panos" "html"}}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{> afFieldInput name="servicesSelected.twilightPhotos.selected" type="boolean-checkbox" noselect="true"}}
      <div class="divider small-margins">
      </div>
      <div class="item-description">
        <p><b>{{formatToCurrency currentPrice.twilightPhotos}}</b> - {{services "twilightPhotos" "description"}}</p>
        <p>{{{services "twilightPhotos" "html"}}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{> afFieldInput name="servicesSelected.exteriors.selected" type="boolean-checkbox" noselect="true"}}
      <div class="divider small-margins">
      </div>
      <div class="item-description">
        <p><b>{{formatToCurrency currentPrice.exteriors}}</b> - {{services "exteriors" "description"}}</p>
        <p>{{{services "exteriors" "html"}}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I wasn't able to get it to work with string concatenation:

```
itemBlock: function(sku){
    var string = ''  +
    '<div class="col-md-12">' +
      '{{> afFieldInput class="track-order-change label-to-bold-if-checked" name="servicesSelected.hdrPhotos.selected" type="boolean-checkbox" noselect="true"}}' +
    '<div class="divider small-margins">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="item-description">' +
    '<p><b>{{formatToCurrency currentPrice.' + sku + '}}</b> - {{services "' + sku + '" "description"}}</p>' +
    '<p>{{{services "' + sku + '" "html"}}}</p>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>';

return string;
}
```

In my html template:

```
{{{itemBlock hdrPhotos}}}
```

The HTML portion of it comes out fine, but everything inside {{ }} and {{{ }}} gets rendered on the page in the literal form (see screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try with [nested sub-expressions](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#nested-sub-expressions) in a dedicated template.

`{{ > yourSkuTemplate "youSkuType"}}`

```
<template name="yourSkuTemplate ">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{> afFieldInput name=(skuServicesSelected) type="boolean-checkbox" noselect="true"}}
      <div class="divider small-margins">
      </div>
      <div class="item-description">
        <p><b>{{formatToCurrency (skuCurrentPrice)}}</b> - {{services (skuName) (skuyDescription}}</p>
        <p>{{{services (skuName) (whatever)}}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Where `skuServicesSelected` `skuName` and all the other in parenthesis are other helpers

Comment: Haha, guh, I was hoping not to have to do this. I'll give it a shot. The tricky part is `{{> afFieldInput }}` comes from a package, so I can't really go about modifying it to accept additional inputs.

Comment: lol yes it is dirty :-) But concerning the `{{> afFieldInput }}` you don't modify it, you just dynamically write the line where you call it using the right value.

Comment: See screenshot I added to the OP.

Comment: What you might need is a way to call spacebars html generation from javascript. However, I am not sure it is possible, and it is getting weird.

Comment: Correct. I'm also not sure how to manually force it to parse spacebars.

Comment: Maybe try it by wrapping your spacebars code in the string with `Spacebars.SafeString("{{> afFieldInput name=\"servicesSelected." + sku + ".selected\"...)`